# ocmock class objects discoverable using objc_getClassList after deallocation and call to -stopMocking

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, ocmock

I am using OCMock to create some class mocks in an XCTest test suite.  I also have a specific unit test where I mock nothing, in a separate test class/module.  This test queries the runtime to look for a set of my classes with a specific prefix that conform to NSSecureCoding and perform several tests on them.

In the test, I obtain the list of classes using objc_getClassList.  I am seeing a number of what looked to be mocked classes still hanging around, for example:

FooType-0x004fba20-3301757833

I can't seem to figure out why they are still hanging around because:

1. I called -stopMocking in the test -tearDown
2. I didn't stub any class methods, only instance methods

I have narrowed it down to the fact that the mocked objects were copied in the initializer of another non-mocked object in a separate test and test class/module.

Obviously, if you try to send a message to these classes or manipulate them, you crash with something akin to  "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "No mock for class FooType-(address masked)-3301757833".

I was under the impression that the meta classes and mocks would be returned to normal when they were de-allocated or -stopMocking was called on them.

Comment: This is using ocmock 3.0.

Comment: Simple: OCMock [does not use `objc_disposeClassPair`](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=objc_disposeClassPair). Personally, I would send a PR to fix that.

Comment: Good call.  I created a [PR](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/pull/272)